# Django post task result to form

Tags: django, database, sqlite, task, celery

i am working on django and i have build an email crawler which finds the emails on the links of a base url...
i want to enter the results to the db.sqlite3 file that is the site database.
my crawler works in the backround as a celery task.
what are the ways that i can make the task add it at the end to the database. 
i am trying to do it with post method but have no luck.

tasks.py

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from .forms import CrawlUpForm
from .craw import crawler
import time
app = Celery(broker='amqp://')
@app.task
def startcraw(base,url,emails):
mylist= crawler(base,url,emails)
for em in mylist:
    new_entry = Crawler(site=base, max_links=20, max_emails=333,emails=em)
    new_entry.save()
answer= ', '.join(mylist)
return answer
```

i want to add the answer to the sql database (it contains email, links and other stuff)

my views.py:

```
from tasks import startcraw
import time
def home(request):
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
    save_it= form.save(commit=False)
    save_it.save()
    messages.success(request,"Working, please wait........")
    baseurl=form.cleaned_data['site']
    maxemails=form.cleaned_data['max_emails']
    maxurl=form.cleaned_data['max_links']
    startcraw.delay(base=baseurl,url=maxurl,emails=maxemails)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/done/')
return render_to_response("signup.html",locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

models.py:

```
class Crawler(models.Model):
site=models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=False)
max_links=models.IntegerField(default=5,max_length=10,blank=True)
max_emails=models.IntegerField(default=5,max_length=10,blank=True)
emails = models.CharField(max_length=999999,null=True,blank=False)
```

i add the models.py.
in my tasks.py i receive in mylist var a list of emails
dont care about the others variables now...

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to post it? You have direct access to the models from your Celery script, simply create it there.

Comment: i couldnt understand how to add it direct... can you give me a little example?

Comment: Do you know how to create model instances in your code? If not then you should do the Django tutorial, where that is explained fully.

Comment: i tried to understand from there but what i am tring to do not working

Comment: you all know to vote up and down but not willing to give a little help, i have read the tutorials and i have buikd a project with celery and such and i have trouble adding data to the db file

Comment: Well, at the last count I've answered almost 6,000 questions here on StackOverflow so you'll excuse me if I don't take that accusation particularly seriously. If you don't know how to do the basics in Django - and saving data in a model is as basic as it gets - you should go and do that tutorial again, and make sure you understand it before trying more complex things like Celery.

Comment: i don`t care about the down vote, it`s legit to down vote a question if you think its deserve it , but still it is a Q&A site so a little look on my question and a little answer would have been appreciated specially when my creating command is good, and after retype and reboot of all system it worked...